# Managing Money for a friend

Tags: united-states, securities

Person X asks person Y to manage a brokerage account for him. Person X asks that the money be managed in a conservative way. Person Y agrees to do. Person X does not compensation person Y in any way.

Person Y then aggressively invests the money and loses most of it. Can person X sue and win?

Comment: Idk if they have standing, but since being agressive/conservative with investments is extremely subjective, good luck proving it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possibly

Person Y is possibly in a [fiduciary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiduciary) relationship with Person X. Person Y is acting as an agent and possibly a broker for Person Y - both of these positions create a fiduciary relationship.

> A fiduciary is someone who has undertaken to act for and on behalf of another in a particular matter in circumstances which give rise to a relationship of trust and confidence.
>
> — Lord Millett, *Bristol and West Building Society v Mothew*

The fiduciary's duty is to act in the other person's best interests. That does not necessarily mean following the other person's instructions, but if they don't, they should have a very good reason for why they didn't.

Comment: Can't you provide some certainty?

Comment: @Greendrake what? And do the courts out if their livelihood? This is an equitable remedy which means it’s at the discretion of the court who will need to consider a lot of circumstances that have not been shared.

Comment: Court's discretion does not mean complete arbitrariness. There is always a principle which is to be followed. The circumstances are all simple, provided in the question.

Comment: @DaleM What factors, not started in the question, would create a fiduciary relationship?

Comment: @Bob Details of the relationship

Answer (score -2):

> Can person X sue and win?

No (unless they bribe the judge).

### No contract

There is no contract for 2 reasons:

- Lack of [consideration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consideration)
- Lack of [intention to create legal relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intention_to_create_legal_relations). By default, friends' gentlemen agreements bear no such intention unless written down and signed.

### No fiduciary duty

Friendship alone [does not](https://www.hbwvlaw.com/blog/court-rules-old-friendship-does-not-equal-a-fiduciary-relationship/) usually equal a fiduciary relationship ([*Gill v. Grewal*, No. 4:14-cv-2502](https://casetext.com/case/gill-v-grewal-2)).

---

However, if there is proof that Y did something malicious (e.g. set up the targets of those aggressive investments to channel the funds into their pocket), they could be prosecuted.

Comment: A contract is also a contract regardless of form, unless otherwise stated by law (e. g. for real estate in Germany a written contract sign by a solicitor)

Comment: @planetmaker If X and Y were strangers to each other, a verbal contract would be fine. Not so when they are friends — some extra evidence is required e.g. a written contract, even if not required by statute.